# angular populate dropdown from object laravel

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, html-select

Hi I'm using Angualr in order to populate select box, I am fetching a list of tags which are grouped together as follows (I've encoded in JSON using Laravel so that I can output it in a friendly format.);

Effort options to be populated in selected

```
{
 "5. XS":{"94":"01:00:00"},
 "4. S":{"96":"02:00:00"},
 "3. M":{"98":"04:00:00"},
 "2. L":{"100":"07:00:00"},"
 1. XL":{"102":"16:00:00"},
"0. XXL":{"104":"38:00:00"},
"105":"Estimate Required"
}
```

I also pass back the selected effort as follows;

```
{"67","697"}
```

Then in angular I do the following:

```
Planning.groom(id)
            .success(function (planning) {
                $scope.tasks = planningtasks;
                $scope.name = planning.name
                $scope.id = planning.id;
                $scope.auth = planning.auth;
                $scope.effortTags = planning.effort;                
            });
```

Then in my view I do the following;

```
 <select ng-model="entity.selected_tags.effort"
         ng-options="effort for effort in effortTags.effort">
  </select>
```

However I can't seem to get the options to be displayed, any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

I'm looking to recreate this dropdown with option groups, but some of the options may not have option groups, they may be an option in its own right, as in shown above in option "Estimate Required";

[image]

Which I've already been able to do using Laravel and jQuery.

Comment: What are you doing in the view? It seems that the editor dropped that part ...

Comment: @NicBright I've formatted my question, should be visible now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to restructure the underlying JSON, e.g. like so

```
$scope.effortTags = [
     { category: "5. XS", id: "94", value: "01:00:00" },
     { category: "4. S", id: "96", value: "02:00:00" },
     { category: "3. M", id: "94", value: "04:00:00" },
     { category: "2. L", id: "94", value: "07:00:00" },
     { category: "1. XL", id: "94", value: "16:00:00" },
     { category: "0. XXL", id: "94", value: "38:00:00" },
     { id: "105", value: "Estimate Required" }
  ];
```

Then you can do this in the template:

```
<select ng-model="entity.selected_tags.effort"
         ng-options="effort as effort.value group by effort.category for effort in effortTags">
</select>
```

Comment: thanks I've done that but now only the categories are displayed and I get [object object] returned in the select

Comment: e.g. <optgroup label="5. XS"><option label="[object Object]" value="string:01:00:00">[object Object]</option></optgroup>

Comment: even when i use the $scope.effortTags you pasted I get this object returned too, so I've structured it in the way you requested

Comment: do you have a plunkr/jsfiddle/jsbin/codepen somewhere?

Comment: ah Ok I'm sorry i got the ng-options part wrong. See here http://jsfiddle.net/cda0gu6y/3/ I'll also update the answer

Comment: thanks! thats worked, however it has already selected the id that I've passed in, do you why this is? do i need to pass it in with a key of 'id'??

Comment: In your example it does not select anything by default? Do you want to have this behaviour? If so you need to prime the $scope.selected variable with the exact same object you wan't to have selected initially.

Comment: my example picture does its just cropped off. sorry. yes i do want this behaviour. i updated the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gutigrewal/cda0gu6y/4/ with the same object but it didn't select it by default

Comment: No in your example it is not the same object. It just looks like if it was the same object. See this working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o9sn5gb4/1/